# How to enter the text in the Text Field in Android Emulator Using Monkey runner

Tags: monkeyrunner

I am using monkey runner.

I have on Screen 1 and I need to fill the form of the page and submit.

I need to take the focus to the first field and need to enter the text.

How to give the focus to any text field or can i type any way?

Please let me know..

REgards,
Chandra

Comment: Can you please, tell me how to run a monkey script? I wrote this command in commadprompt "android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner test.py" and got following error

Error: Can't open specified script file Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE -s MonkeyServer IP Address. -p MonkeyServer TCP Port. -v MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF) –

Comment: you have to save as .mr and try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can focus on a text field and type text in that field.

I did it using Python. Followings are relevant lines from my code:

```
import os, subprocess
import sys
import time
import random
import string
import re
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

#connect to the device
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(99, "emulator-5554")
```

Then, launch the relevant activity and move to the text field using the press function.

```
device.press ('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)# move down
```

Normally, when you reach a text field then focus is already there, but if it is not then click the field.

```
device.press ('KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)#click the field
```

Now, one can type the text using the type function.

```
device.type('text')
```